# human synonym for the word 'medicine'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, british-english, epithet-requests

What is the human synonym for the word 'medicine'? Basically,  I want to know  what do we call a human who can act like a medicine for curing our emotional wounds?

Comment: A *priest* / *rabbi* / *imam* / *psychologist* / *psychiatrist* / *friend* / *parent* / *sibling*?

Comment: 'Antidote' is broad enough to include humans. For example: "The serene Anny was the perfect antidote for Paul's nervous restlessness."

Answer (score 3):

In this context [***healer***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/healer) might work:

> - A person or thing that mends or repairs something

The 'something' can cover a range of things including physical, mental and emotional.

Answer (score 2):

Probably ***[psychotherapy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/psychotherapy)*** is close to what you are looking for:

> - treatment of mental or emotional illness by talking about problems rather than by using medicine or drugs.

[Psychotherapist](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/psychotherapist) is the person who gives psychotherapy

(M-W)

Comment: Upvote for great minds thinking alike, but I'd suggest *psychotherapist*, as OP is looking for a person, rather than a methodology.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word you are looking for is **[Consoler](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/consoler)**, which Noah Webster defines as "One that gives comfort." in The American Dictionary of the English Language (A.D.E.L.), or more specifically, a consoler is a person who consoles other people. A.D.E.L. defines [console](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/console) as:

> verb transitive [Latin The primary sense is either to set or allay, to give rest or quiet, or the sense is to strengthen, in which case it coincides with the root of solid. The latter is most probable.]
>
> To comfort; to cheer the mind in distress or depression; to alleviate grief, and give refreshment to the mind or spirits; to give contentment or moderate happiness by relieving from distress.

I doubt any further explanation is necessary, although it may be worth note that the words like [alleviate](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/alleviate) is a word often used in medical contexts.

> "1. To make light; but always in a figurative sense, as it is not applied to material objects. To remove in part; to lessen, mitigate, or make easier to be endured; applied to evils; as, to alleviate sorrow, pain, care, punishment, a burden, &c.; opposed to aggravate." — A.D.E.L.

Hence alleviation in the context of consolation refers to relieving ourselves of mental pain, anguish, sorrow and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The original "Star Trek" TV series had an episode with such a character, who was known as the *Empath.* This is not a recognized word, although the back-formation from *empathy* is obvious.

Comment: I don't remember that.  I was thinking of Deanna Troi in TNG.  Put in a reference and link, and I'll upvote if you notify me.

Comment: Empath didn't mean this in the context of Star Trek: The Next Generation, but instead referred to a person who had the psychic power to sense another person's emotions, which is (almost) what empathy is. However, despite being helpful, merely knowing another person's emotional state doesn't necessarily do anything to improve it. Dianna Troi had that ability but her job title on the ship is more relevant. A cursory glance reveals to me that they seem to have used the wrong word in her title instead of the proper one though, which is a shame, since it would've made a very good example otherwise.